# Bash or condition using variable and numeric value

Tags: bash

I have two variables `$filetr_exec` and `$filetr_dryrun`.  I want to append
`--dry-run` to the array `oser` whenever `filetr_dryrun == 1` or `filetr_exec`
is not set.  This means that if both are set, I still append `--dry-run` to `oser`.

Would need something as follows, but do not know how to check both existence
of a variable and a numerical value.

```
if [[ -z $filetr_exec ]] || (( filetr_dryrun == 1 )); then
  oser+=( --dry-run )
fi
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't that work like you showed? Technically, `[[ -z $var ]]` checks if the variable is either unset or set to the empty string, but that's probably not a problem.

Comment: Am still going through testing it.  Seems I can mix the conditions this way.

Comment: What happens when you try this? Are there any error messages or does it just not behave as you expect? And, if the latter, how does it behave?

Comment: @Pietru, yes. `[[ .. ]]` and `(( .. ))` are command-like constructs by themselves and `||` can take any commands on both sides, so that's fine. (Also, `[ .. ]` is an _actual_ command, just one with a weird name.) Or if you don't need actual numbers, just yes/no, you could do `[[ -z $filetr_exec ]] || [[ -n $filetr_dryrun ]]` to use the same on both sides. (`[[ -n $var ]]` would check if the variable is set to anything but the empty string. Even if it's the string `no`.)

Comment: Thanks ilkkachu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like ilkkachu said, this should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

filetr_exec="" #or 1
filetr_dryrun="" #or 1
oser=(--test)

if [[ -z "$filetr_exec" ]] || (( filetr_dryrun == 1 )); then
  oser+=( --dry-run )
fi

printf '%s\n' "${oser[@]}"
```

Always prints the expected values for me.